# How to make the turtlebot move with path?(related to AMCL)

Tags: navigation, turtlebot2, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm using ROS kinect on Ubuntu 16.04.

I'm trying to get my turtlebot move in the navigation environment and made AML files for it like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<launch>

<arg name="map_file" default="$(find teb_navigation)/maps/my_map.yaml"/>
<node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)" />

<arg name="use_map_topic" default="true"/>
<arg name="scan_topic" default="scan" />

<node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl">
    <param name="use_map_topic" value="$(arg use_map_topic)"/>
    <!-- Publish scans from best pose at a max of 10 Hz -->
    <param name="odom_model_type" value="diff"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha5" value="0.1"/>
    <param name="gui_publish_rate" value="10.0"/>
    <param name="laser_max_beams" value="60"/>
    <param name="laser_max_range" value="12.0"/>
    <param name="min_particles" value="500"/>
    <param name="max_particles" value="2000"/>
    <param name="kld_err" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="kld_z" value="0.99"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha1" value="0.2"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha2" value="0.2"/>
    <!-- translation std dev, m -->
    <param name="odom_alpha3" value="0.2"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha4" value="0.2"/>
    <param name="laser_z_hit" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="laser_z_short" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="laser_z_max" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="laser_z_rand" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="laser_sigma_hit" value="0.2"/>
    <param name="laser_lambda_short" value="0.1"/>
    <param name="laser_model_type" value="likelihood_field"/>
    <!-- <param name="laser_model_type" value="beam"/> -->
    <param name="laser_likelihood_max_dist" value="2.0"/>
    <param name="update_min_d" value="0.25"/>
    <param name="update_min_a" value="0.2"/>
    <param name="odom_frame_id" value="odom"/>
    <param name="resample_interval" value="1"/>
    <!-- Increase tolerance because the computer can get quite busy -->
    <param name="transform_tolerance" value="1.0"/>
    <param name="recovery_alpha_slow" value="0.0"/>
    <param name="recovery_alpha_fast" value="0.0"/>
    <remap from="scan" to="$(arg scan_topic)"/>    
</node>

</launch>
```

the above is the amcl file.
Can I give tuertle bot movement with these below??

> $ roslauch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot tuetlebot_world.launch

> $ roalcunch teb_navigation amcl1.launch

At least in my case, I failed; it can make path-plan but couldn't move at all.
So I added `move_base` node additionally like below:

```
<launch>

<!--- Run AMCL -->
<include file="$(find teb_navigation)/launch/amcl.launch" />

<node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">

    <param name="base_global_planner" value="navfn/NavfnROS"/>
    <param name="base_local_planner" value="dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS"/>
    <rosparam file="$(find teb_navigation)/config/base_global_planner.yaml" command="load"/>
    <rosparam file="$(find teb_navigation)/config/base_local_planner.yaml" command="load"/>

    <!-- observation sources located in costmap_common.yaml -->
    <rosparam file="$(find teb_navigation)/config/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find teb_navigation)/config/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />

    <!-- local costmap, needs size -->
    <rosparam file="$(find teb_navigation)/config/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <param name="local_costmap/width" value="10.0"/>
    <param name="local_costmap/height" value="10.0"/>

    <!-- static global costmap, static map provides size -->
    <rosparam file="$(find teb_navigation)/config/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap"/>
    
</node>

</launch>
```

and it works.
But, the tutorials I read, the tutorial's robot can navigate with just `amcl1.launch`.
Although I made my files based on turtlebot's those...
Is it possible to get some movements with only `amcl` part?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342239/how-to-make-the-turtlebot-move-with-path?(related-to-amcl)/) by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2020-01-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2020-01-22**:
can you please leave links to the tutorials that you have read/used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Even though [amcl](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl?distro=melodic) is a part of the navigation stack, it is a localization package and you cant navigate with it. For navigation you need [move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation) and that is why your second launch file works.

```
  roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch
```

will just launch the turtlebot gazebo simulation which will simulate your robot with all the required senors in an environment

```
roslaunch teb_navigation amcl1.launch
```

while the above will launch only the `amcl` localization and map server (as shown in your first launch file). You can launch `move_base` here or create a separate launch file for navigation.

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2020-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on 2020-01-22**:
Thanks for your quick reply. I think [the tutorial](https://www.robotigniteacademy.com/en/course/teb-local-planner_29_0/) I referred to is not accessible because it is not open source. However, I'm now sure that with only `amcl` it is not possible to make the robot move, thanks to you. Now I wonder the robot can move with just the code I made,`move_base.launch` (Just so you know, the first code is `amcl1.lauch`, and the other one is `move_base.launch`). In the case of `turtlebot`, the `amcl_demo.launch' includes the following:

```
  <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/velocity_smoother.launch.xml"/>
  <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/safety_controller.launch.xml"/>
```

And when I just added the above two lines and also the corresponded parameters setting,

```
     <remap from="cmd_vel" to="navigation_velocity_smoother/raw_cmd_vel"/>
```

Then it moved with path plans.

**Comment by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on 2020-01-22**:
Is it imperative to set the node which has something to do with `cmd_vel`?
(I didn't add any lines related to `cmd_vel` in `move_base.launch` indeed.)

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2020-01-23**:
You dont actually need `velocity_smoother` and `safety_controller` to navigate. The velocity_smoother is used for smoother `cmd_vels` while the `safety_controller` I guess is a wrapper around `kobuki_safety_controller` for bumper/cliff detection (I am not familiar with the turtlebot stack much) so in the end they are just used to improve the navigation run by `move_base`.

**Comment by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on 2020-01-23**:
Thanks for your re-relpy. However without `velocity_smoother`, it did not show any little movements at all. As far as I know,  `cmd_vel`, whatever its name would be remapped, is the most essential to move a mobile robot. Actually, all that I did was launching `amcl` and `move_base` node without any kind mentions of `cmd_vel`, described above, `move_base.launch`. Does `move_base` node address `cmd_vel` inherently?

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2020-01-24**:
well `move_base` is the one that outputs a `cmd_vel` topic. The `velocity_smoother` just uses that topic to smooth the values I guess so probably you have some remapping mismatch somewhere in your launch files. You should check how many `cmd_vel` topics you have in the end and remap properly

**Comment by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on 2020-01-27**:
Thank you so much, I'll try it and notify you as soon as possible